# Neovim t and f have the same exclusive behavior in operator mode

Tags: neovim

I am migrating slowly from Vim to Neovim, and there is one habit that I have of using `t` or `f` in operator pending mode in vim that does not work the same way in Neovim.

When used after `d`, `v`, `y`, or `c` in operator pending mode in Neovim, `f` behaves exactly like `t` in an exclusive fashion whereas in Vim, `f` has an inclusive effect.

I tried in Neovim with empty config and no plugins to make sure there are no conflicts, and I read some `help` sections about `selection`, `select-mode` but I cannot figure out the cause of the problem.

I am using Neovim 0.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, and I tried in both kitty and konsole for the same results.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a serious regression. You should probably use their issue tracker directly.

Comment: In 0.7.0 the behavior matches vim.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that you do not experience this odd behavior. After heading to neovim issue tracker, I learnt about `nvim --clean` which by the way does not show in my `nvim --help` output, and starting nvim this way, I cannot reproduce the issue. Obviously the issue is on my side I need to figure out the difference between `nvim --clean` and `nvim -u empty.lua --noplugin`.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a plugin conflict, even though I still do not know why I was able to reproduce the issue starting neovim with `--noplugin`, the `--clean` flag made it clear that it was a problem on my side, and I was finally able to isolate the plugin responsible.

Thank you for your help.